# How to obtain a specific CacheManager in Spring Boot 3?

Tags: spring-boot, caching

In a Spring Boot 3 application I want to obtain a specific `CacheManager`.

Debugging the application says, that there are 2 cache managers in use: the `urn:X-ehcache:jsr107-default-config` manager (red box) with no active caches and a custom configured `classpath:ehcache.xml` manager (green box) where all the configured caches are located.

[image: Cache managers]

The `org.springframework.cache.CacheManager` injected by Spring Boot delivers the default one (red box) which doesn't have any use for me. What I want is to obtain the custom cache manager (green box).

I've tried the following to get hands on the desired manager:

```java
try {

    URI ehcacheXmlUri = new URI("classpath:ehcache.xml");
    CachingProvider cachingProvider = Caching.getCachingProvider();
    CacheManager cacheManager = cachingProvider.getCacheManager(ehcacheXmlUri, getClass().getClassLoader());

} catch (IOException e) { }
```

Unfortunately, doing so registers the same configuration a second time with the application:

```
o.e.s.o.t.o.p.UpfrontAllocatingPageSource : Allocating 1MB in chunks
o.e.c.EhcacheManager                      : Cache 'email-status-cache' created in EhcacheManager.
o.e.j.Eh107CacheManager                   : Registering Ehcache MBean javax.cache:type=CacheStatistics,CacheManager=classpath.ehcache.xml,Cache=email-status-cache
```

So although `getCacheManager()` would suggest to only retrieve an existing manager, in my specific case this method registers another manager and all caches again. After this, I end up with another `classpath:ehcache.xml` manager (orange box):

[image: Cache managers]

I think that has something to do with the underlying `Classloader` and therefore maybe `getClass().getClassLoader()` is not the right way to provide the required class loader?

So my questions are:

- How do I obtain the desired CacheManager (green box), the one which is already known to the application and has access to the already registered caches?
- How can I provide the correct class loader?

Many thanks for any help.